# How can I use tokens in my content

Tags: nodes, tokens

I want to use tokens in my content but it seems like it doesn't let me. I've found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228506/how-can-i-use-tokens-in-node-pages-in-drupal) about using the [Token Filter module](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) but I have not been able to configure it so that it would print. In the [README.TXT](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/token_filter/plain/README.txt?id=refs/heads/6.x-1.x) it says,

> Go to /admin/settings/filters and enable the token_filter for any of
>   your existing filter type    or if you wish, create a new one.

but my problem is, when I go to http://127.0.0.1/drupal-7.34/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fsettings%252Ffilters (on my installation, I just get to see [image] and I'm not sure how I can "enable the token_filter for any of your existing filter type" - may anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually in order for this to work you need the token filter module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter

Otherwise there is no option in text format config.

Answer (score 0):

README file of D7 version of module seems to be outdated, couple of things to ensure here:

1. [Token filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module is enabled.
2. Navigate to text format section: `Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring` (URL: `<DOMAIN-URL>/admin/config/content/formats`)
3. Either edit any of the existing text formats or else create new text format and select the option: `Replace tokens`
4. Now verify `Filter processing order` present just below this options, to make sure `Replace tokens` doesn't overridden by some other option.
5. Check permission for this updated/created text format (required user roles have permission to access this text format)
6. Try creating content, however ensure the text format is one update/create above.

Answer (score -1):

On Drupal 7, you set the text formats at admin/config/content/formats; so, on your site it should be http://127.0.0.1/drupal-7.34/admin/config/content/formats. Click on *configure* for the format you want to change.